# richtextbox advanced editing

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, toolbar

I want to use advanced editing features with a RichTextBox I am using. For example, bold, italic, underline, font color....

I was wondering how I would get a toolbar that would show up at the top of the RichTextBox with those features? And I was wondering if there was anything that offered this functionality built in, or am I going to have to create all of it myself?

I was thinking that the richtextbox would come with that toolbar by default, but it doesn't seem too.

Comment: yes by default rich textbox doesn't have such kind of features.

Comment: This has been done many times, you'll find lots of examples at codeproject.com

Comment: @ Hans: any chance you can link me to an example?

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I actually found what i wanted. Here are my results:

[This one offers bullets and more stuff.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RicherTextBox.aspx) I chose this one, because it offered bullets.

[This one offers more of the basic stuff.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/richtextboxextended.aspx)