# VB.Net Form Controls For Formatting A Rich Text Box

Tags: vb.net, formatting, richtextbox

I'm looking for a way to allow users to format text in a rich text box before submitting the `.rtf` to a database.

I'm looking to allow users to highlight text in the text box and then make it bold, change the font size, colour etc. All the classic controls you find in word basically.

Short of writing my own controls, is there any way of achieving this? I'd rather steer clear of 3rd party stuff, but if there is anything that is worth it I could check it out.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to write your own control or use one someone else has made.  The standard RichTextBox doesn't support much.

This one looks decent: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24443/RicherTextBox

It was mentioned in: [richtextbox advanced editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028915/richtextbox-advanced-editing)